# Drag and drop file upload library for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I found a great library called [JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for drag-and-drop files uploads in modern browsers. Unfortunately drag-and-drop does not work in Internet Explorer.

Drag-and-drop file upload in IE is a requirement of the project, so I'd like to find a solution for this specific situation. My idea is to end up with two versions of the upload page, one for IE, and another one for the rest of the world.

Does anyone know a good activex library for such uploads in IE, that does not require any installation?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way is to use the new HTML5 Drag and Drop API and new File API.

Comment: I believe the TO wanted a solution for older versions of IE, no HTML5 drag-n-drop API support.

Comment: Okay ! I think FileDrop is what you need --> [link](http://proger.i-forge.net/FileDrop_%E2%80%93_cross-browser_JavaScript_Drag_-amp_Drop_file_upload/7CC)

Comment: FileDrop apparently makes it possible to upload files through Drag'n Drop and IE6+ trough an iframe trick. I have to check that, but it looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try [dropZone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone), support IE 10+

Answer (score 0):

[FiledropJS 2](http://filedropjs.org/), is a drag and drop file upload library, which has an  [`<Iframe>` based fallback](http://filedropjs.org/#sif) for working in older IE's as well. There is a demo in that page. It looks promising, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a javascript module to do generalized drag and drop events including:

- file dropping,
- drag and drop within a browser window,
- drag and drop between two different browser windows,
- drag and drop from a browser window to an external application, and
- drag and drop from an external application to a browser window

It abstracts away a bunch of bizzaro things about the html5 drag and drop api that would otherwise waste hours of your time. Here's an example usage:

```
dd.drag(myDomNode, {
    dragImage: true, // default drag image
    start: function(setData, e) {
        setData('myCustomData', JSON.stringify({a:1, b:"NOT THE BEES"})) // camel case types are allowed!*
    }
})
dd.drop(myDropzone, {
    drop: function(data, pointer, e) {
        myDropzone.innerHTML = data.myCustomData
    }
})
```

It works in IE as well (with the usual IE caveats). Check out the full documentation here: https://github.com/fresheneesz/drip-drop